# Using Laravel with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: php, visual-studio, laravel, laravel-5, visual-studio-2017

I'm starting a new project in the company where I work, for this new project we will use Laravel, the problem is that the boss as decided that we must use Visual Studio 2017(I don't know why and I can't do nothing about it)...
So I installed PHP Tools, but when I start the debug the browser navigate to 
`http://localhost:55929/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=21C25293`
and appear the message
`The requested resource /?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=21C25293 was not found on this server.`

What must I do to using Laravel with Visual Studio 2017 and to debug it?

Sorry for my poor english...

**UPDATE**

For everyone other has this problem, the solution is to inserting `public/` in `Debug/Properties/Application/Web root`

Comment: Sounds like XDebug is not enabled within PHP. Or the base directory is not set correctly.

Comment: You need to setup your webserver and project URL correctly otherwise visual studio will try to create a new page setup in IIS and probably fail because it's not a .NET Web project.

Comment: in Debug/Properties/Server theese are my settings:

Server: Buil-in Web Server;
Runtime: PHP 7.1.7;
Host name: localhost;
Auto-assign port;

Comment: Hi @davidinho, I tried to put my public folder in the location as you mentioned, but didn't work, any workaround